# wait data before launching onMapReady callback

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-maps-v2

I implement a map on my activity but latitude and longitude are coming from a server.
AsyncTask is requesting for those values but I don't know how I can wait for data to be received before launching the OnMapReadyCallback callback...

here's my code:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
....
//retrieve the latitude and longitude
new ProgressTask().execute();

m = ((SupportMapFragment) this.getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map));   
//need to wait for AsyncTask...
m.getMapAsync(this);
```

I expected to launch the command

```
m.getMapAsync(this);
```

in the onPostExecute of my AsyncTask:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(OnMapReadyCallback result) {
....
....
```

but I don't know how to pass in params the OnMapReadyCallback to the AsyncTask ?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution (not sure this is the best one...) to retrieve the context of My Activity (which implements OnMapReadyCallback) I'm just calling the

```
m.getMapAsync(this);
```

from a method out of onPOstExecute:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Fragment result) {
....
loadMap();
}

public void loadMap(){

    m.getMapAsync(this);
}
```